# Excel: Selecting a random sample from triangulated data

Tags: excel, statistics, excel-formula, random, resampling

I want to select a (selection of)number(s) at random from a triangular table. How would I go about doing this?
 Or if anybody has a more sophisticated/efficient way of bootstrapping that would be great. The table needs to be in a format as below:

```
x  x  x  x 
x  x  x 
x  x 
x
```

Can someone help me with this or point me in the right direction? I've done a lot of searching online but can't seem to find anything useful.

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell outside the *triangle* and enter:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,A4)
```

For example:

[image]

The *Choose()* function is limited, but it can handle 10 options.